# How to use Color with RGB or hex value in SwiftUI using Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, colors, swiftui, background-color

I am currently trying to change the background color of a Label in `SwiftUI`. As far as I know, SwiftUI takes a View as the parameter for the background Modifier.

However, I encountered a problem I am not able to fix:

I would like to change the background color of my Label by using a hex code or an RGB value. Because of some reason, when doing so the background color always changes to white.

This works perfectly fine:

```swift
Label(
    title: { Text("someTitle") },
    icon: { Image(systemName: "someName") }
)
.background(Color.purple) // Using the provided standard Colors works perfectly fine.
```

However, I would like to create a background color using a hex or RGB value:

```swift
.background(Color(Color.RGBColorSpace.sRGB, red: 92, green: 225, blue: 230, opacity: 1))
// or
.background(Color(UIColor(red: 220, green: 24, blue: 311, alpha: 1)))
```

This does not work and the background color of the Label always changes back to white. How to achieve this goal?

Comment: `Color(UIColor(red: 220/255, green: 24/255, blue: 311/255, alpha: 1)`

Comment: Leo Dabus provides an answer that worked for me, because it is in Swift!  The main answer in "how to create a UIColor" is how to #define a macro to do this, but ... this doesn't work inSwift! :-) Thanks, Leo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UIColor init method `UIColor(red:green:blue:alpha)` takes float values from 0 to 1 for each value.

Any value ≥ 1.0 is going to "max out" that color. So an expression like `UIColor(red: 220, green: 24, blue: 311, alpha: 1)` will set all 3 color channels *and* alpha to 1.0, resulting in white. So would `UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)`

You could create an extension to UIColor that adds convenience initializers that would take values of different types. First, and initializer that would take values from 0-255 for each. Then you could create another intializer `UIColor.init(hexString:String)`.

The one that took values from 0-255 would be a lot easier to write. The one that took hex strings would involve implementing a hex parser. I bet somebody has already written it though.

Take a look at this code, for example:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fd07ecf47591c9f9ed1a

Comment: This should be closed as duplicate. Btw perfect timing with my comment. Same second

Comment: Note: **On applications linked for iOS 10 or later, the color is specified in an extended color space, and the input value is never clamped.** Of course that for such high values it would make it always return white